# Live webcam website architecture?

Tags: flash, adobe, rtmfp

I want people to be able to create a "room" and let other people join the room and be able to watch the room's owner through his webcam. Basically, something similar to Stickam.

So I did some googling and found out that the best way to achieve this would be by using the RTMF protocol. So I installed the Adobe Flex compiler, downloaded an example app which contains some ActionScript files, an MXML file and one Python script.

So how exactly am I supposed to get something running out of this? Do I need to code everything in ActionScript, or can I use Python or something else to communicate with the Flash app? Also, is extended knowledge of ActionScript necessary to build something like this?

Answer (score 2):

For sure you will need a server side application to run and get the webcam's stream to provide it to your users.

Flash side is the client side, you can use flash to "capture" the room's owner and also for the viewers to see the room's owner's video.

Unless you found a python script to do the job for you, I can suggest you [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) to start with. This can be the server-side part of the architecture. You will connect to it via this RTMF protocol from the flash. You can also manage live streaming with rooms.

I think you can find some demos included too to start your tests or go on this way to dig into this topic more.

Hope this helps.